# support for std::map< std::string, T > in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there a standard approach to specifying a property to be a dictionary or map keyed by string with a value type T specified somewhere else in the schema?

For example, suppose you want to model a user's favorite movies where the key type is the name of the movie and the value type is some set of attributes about the movie (year made, budget, gross income, etc.)

I imagine you could model first a MovieDataPair as a type with *name* property and a *value* property containing the desired attributes. Then the map would be an array of those. But, then you would need a special unique constraint that ensured any movie name only appeared once.

Is there something in json schema to support this, or a standard pattern used for it?
If not built in support in json schema, what about other schema solutions?

Comment: Thank you for asking (and answering!) this question, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some study I've come up with the following answer:

The best way to see this in action is to find some examples. It
happens that there are several examples of this in the draft04 schema
itself (*definitions*, *properties*, *patternProperties*,...) and they
usually follow the same pattern.

For example, the *definitions* property of the draft04 schema defines what
should appear in a schema at the *definitions* property. Here is the
subschema associated with the *definitions*  property:

```
"definitions": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
    "default": {}
},
```

This says the entry at "#/definitions/" must be an object. The fact
that it is a json object means it will have unique keys itself. Now
for the *values* in the object, that is what *additionalProperties* is
designed to describe. In this case it says that the value of each
property must itself conform to the root of the schema "#". What this
means is that each value in the *definitions* property object of a valid json schema 
object must also be a schema. 
If this were typed like C++ it might look like:

```
std::map< std::string, Schema > definitions;
```

Effectively a map with a string key can be thought of as like a json
object with a structured value type. So, to create your own:

```
std::map< std::string, T >
```

- First define the schema for T. For example:

  ```
  "definitions" : {
     "movie" : {
         "properties": {
            "title" : { "type" : "string" },
            "year_made" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "rating" : { "type" : "integer" }
         }
      }
  }
  ```
- For the value type T stored, decide if you want to allow any
  properties, as long as these specified properties are typed as
  specified above. If you only want these properties, add
  *"additionalProperties" : false*

  ```
   "definitions" : {
     "movie" : {
         "additionalProperties" : false,
         "properties": {
            "title" : { "type" : "string" },
            "year_made" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "rating" : { "type" : "integer" }
         }
      }
   }
  ```
- Also decide if you actually require all of the properties to be
  present for the movie to be valid. If so, add a *required* entry.

  ```
  "definitions" : {
    "movie" : {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required" : [ "title", "year_made", "rating" ],
      "properties": {
        "title" : { "type" : "string" },
        "year_made" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "rating" : { "type" : "integer" }
    }
  },
  ```
- Now the *shape* T for movie is defined. Create a definition for
  the collection, or map of movies referencing the movie schema
  defined as was done by *definitions* in the draft schema. Note: in
  the "movie_map" *additionalProperties* has a different meaning than
  that of "movie". In the case of "movie" it is a boolean *false*
  which indicates no additional properties beyond what is listed in
  *properties*. In the case of "movie_map" it means - *if there are
  additional properties, they must look like this schema*. But,
  since no properties have been specified in *movie_map* it really means 
  all properties in the object instance must conform to #/definitions/movie. Now all
  values in a "movie_map" will look like the defined *movie* schema.

  ```
  {
    "definitions" : {
      "movie" : {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required" : [ "title", "year_made", "rating" ],
        "properties": {
          "title" : { "type" : "string" },
          "year_made" : { "type" : "integer" },
          "rating" : { "type" : "integer" }
        }
      },
      "movie_map" : {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/movie" },
        "default": {}
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Now use the defined schema *movie_map* somewhere within the schema:

  ```
  {
    "title" : "movie data",
    "additionalProperties" : false,
    "required" : [ "movies" ],
    "properties" : {
      "movies" : { "$ref" : "#/definitions/movie_map" }
    },
    "definitions" : {
      "movie" : {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required" : [ "title", "year_made", "rating" ],
        "properties": {
          "title" : { "type" : "string" },
          "year_made" : { "type" : "integer" },
          "rating" : { "type" : "integer" }
        }
      },
      "movie_map" : {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/movie" },
        "default": {}
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Here is a sample object, which can be thought of as a *map*, of movies
that validates against the schema:

```
{
  "movies" : {
    "the mission" : {
      "title":"The Mission",
      "year_made":1986,
      "rating":5
    },
    "troll 2" : {
      "title":"Troll 2",
      "year_made":1990,
      "rating":2
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same use-case, but currently Jackson 2.4.2 modules doesn't get this type of schema for HashMap<String, POJO>, I see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema this module solves this kind of schemas, but it still has a self reference issue, which is going to be fixed in 2.4.1 for this module. So how should we handle these kind of situations for current situations using Jackson Parser. I don't know if it's the right place to ask this question, but seems like you've done a lot of research around this.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to model a structure for users favorites movies (remind Json Schema is intended for structure validation) I would make something  like:

```
{
"description":"moviesFan",
"properties": [
    "favoriteMovies": {
        "type":"array",
        "uniqueItems":True
        "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/movie" }]
    }
],
"definitions": {
    "movie": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "yearMade": {}
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Useful - but I am after specifically a map where key is string (title) and value is set of fixed properties. I want the title to be the key as it is used as the index in code already. After studying the schema documentation I am wondering if I need a patternProperty where the pattern matches any string and its value is desired movie attributes. Or, alternatively maybe the simplest approach is just define additionalProperties only with desired move attributes - which might do it?

Comment: I think I have not understood what you want to achieve. Each movie has a different schema or you want to use Json-Schema to develop a catalog of movies and enforce a sort of "referencial integrity" à la XSD?

Comment: Each movie has the same schema. The json instance will be a collection of those movies stored as values in an *object* (i.e. map). Each movie has a title and I want the title to be the key. e.g. { "Gone With the Wind" : {...}, "War Games" : {...} }. Here the {...} would be the movie attributes described by a schema, say #/definitions/movie, and it may contain the title again. Of course, the title can be any string. I don't need unique for that since it is stored as the key in the json instance.

Comment: And why do you "need" to have the title as a "property name"? Json-Schema is about structure. AFAIK it would not make much sense to have an ever-growing number of property names.

Comment: Well, that is the way the data is already structured. The JSON schema usage is coming second, after the fact. Think of well structured data in a mongo document where the id is a string. Or think of a C++ class where a member of PersonFavorites is std::map< String, MovieDetails > _favoriteMovies;

Comment: A well structured JSON document or an OOP class in any language could have an id/key property. "Gone With the Wind" would be the value of that property. Anyway, Json Schema does not provide what you intent. I would recommend you to try the other option (and then Json Schema or XSD or Avro can fit your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way to support for map. Hope to help.

```
    {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "map data",
      "required": [
        "map"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sOnePurRecord": {
          "title": "map",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "mapItem": {
              "type": "object",
              "maxProperties": 10,
              "minProperties": 1,
              "patternProperties": {
                "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/value"
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/value"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "mapItem"
          ]
        }
      },
      "definitions": {
        "value": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```